# What is being summed in the Bellman Equation and why?

Tags: dynamic-programming

What is being summed and why?
$s'$ is the next state. Don't we just want the next state with the max value?

There is an $s'$ under the summation, so are all the possible $s'$ in $P$ and the $s'$ in $V(s')$ being summed? Or is everything to the right of the summation being summed? The $s$, the $a$, the $s'$ and the $V(s')$?

What exactly is happening and why is it the best thing to do?

$$V(s) = \underset a \max \left( R(s,a) + \gamma \sum_{s'} {P(s,a,s')V(s')}\right)$$

Comment: You can use $L^AT_EX$: Try `$V(s) = \underset a \max ( R(s,a) + \gamma \displaystyle \sum_{s\prime} {P(s,a,s\prime)V(s\prime)})$`.

Comment: Don't use `\prime`. Instead, use `'`.

Comment: Some context is missing here. What are $V,R,P$?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus [Here is a video on the topic](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud600/lessons/bbd1cb1a-7bdd-4d95-9fa8-23f5e53d0903/concepts/35f61bee-aa0b-4c13-b98b-09bf32b89a0c)

Comment: I'm not going to watch a video.

Comment: What research/study have you done?  What have you read?  What do you think the equation *should* look like, instead of a sum?

Comment: @D.W. I wrote in the post "Don't we just want the next state with the max value?"

Comment: What do you think is the correct formula, and why?  Can you provide context, as requested by Yuval Filmus, to make the question self-contained?  There are multiple ways you can improve your question.

Comment: @D.W. I'm just asking about one part of the equation.